# bibliographydriver - error correction

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have written a bibliographydriver to output @jurisdiction in the bibliography. @jurisdiction is already defined in jura2. Only the driver is missing.

My solution approach has the problem that institution and the first \textendash are not displayed.

IS: Urteil vom 27. März 1952 – IV R 356/51 U, BStBl. III 1952, S. 122.
SHOULD: BFH-Urteil vom 27. März 1952 – iV R 356/51 U, BStBl. III 1952, S. 122.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
  @jurisdiction{IV35651U,
gericht = {BFH},
dokumententyp = {Urteil},
entscheidungsdatum = {1952-03-27},
aktenzeichen = {IV R 356/51 U},
fundstelle = {BStBl. III 1952, S. 122},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\setromanfont{Arial}
%\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=jura2,sorting=nty]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Driver; @jurisdiction;biblatex backend=biber style=jura2
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{institution}%
  \setunit{\textendash}%
  \printfield{usera}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext{vom}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace\textendash\addspace}%
   \printfield{userb}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{userd}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}} 
  
  \begin{document}
 
 Referenz\footcite[][]{IV35651U} 
 
  \printbibliography %[nottype=jurisdiction]
  \end {document}
```

Extract from the .bbx file of jura 2

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Änderungen betr. 'jurisdiction'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map[overwrite=false]{
    \pertype{jurisdiction}
    \step[fieldsource=gericht,
          fieldtarget=institution]
    \step[fieldsource=dokumententyp,
          fieldtarget=usera]
    \step[fieldsource=entscheidungsdatum,
          fieldtarget=date]
    \step[fieldsource=aktenzeichen,
          fieldtarget=userb]
    \step[fieldsource=datenbank,
          fieldtarget=userc]
    \step[fieldsource=fundstelle,
          fieldtarget=userd]
    \step[fieldsource=ecli,
          fieldtarget=usere]
    \step[fieldsource=entscheidungsname,
          fieldtarget=userf]
  }}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is jura2? Please explain!

Comment: jura2 is a style for Biblatex. https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-jura2?lang=de

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here

Comment: The output does not match the intended result.
institution and \textendash are not displayed. The questions are why and how do I solve this.

Comment: there is a backslash too much in your example, but beside this I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtFId.png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have revised the file. The bibliography will now be generated.  The footnote will be correctly generated by jura2. The output in the bibliography is generated by the code above. In this specific example, BFH- is missing at the beginning.

Comment: Can this be reproduced with a font everyone has? If so, please remove the dependency on Arial.

Comment: Removed dependency on Arial. The solution from @cfr works both with and without Arial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
  \printlist{institution}%
```

rather than `\printfield{institution}%` in the driver. You need to match the `\print<type>` command to the `<type>` of the relevant field. `institution` is a literal list, so `\printlist` is required here.

I can't test this with precisely your code as I don't possess Arial, which is a commercial font to which I have no access. However, using default fonts, this modification can be seen to fix the issue.

[image: institution in bibliography entry]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
  @jurisdiction{IV35651U,
gericht = {BFH},
dokumententyp = {Urteil},
entscheidungsdatum = {1952-03-27},
aktenzeichen = {IV R 356/51 U},
fundstelle = {BStBl. III 1952, S. 122},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=jura2,sorting=nty]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit{\textendash}%
  \printfield{usera}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext{vom}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace\textendash\addspace}%
  \printfield{userb}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{userd}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}} 

\begin{document}
  
Referenz\footcite[][]{IV35651U} 

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
The solution works perfectly. Fortunately, the font has no influence on the result.